# How to configure the application insights to angular 2 application with typescript using visual studio 2015

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-application-insights

I had developed angular2 application using visual studio 2015. for that application I need to configure the application insights.

This is code I wrote in **index.html**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var appInsights = window.appInsights || function (config) { function i(config) { t[config] = function () { var i = arguments; t.queue.push(function () { t[config].apply(t, i) }) } } var t = { config: config }, u = document, e = window, o = "script", s = "AuthenticatedUserContext", h = "start", c = "stop", l = "Track", a = l + "Event", v = l + "Page", y = u.createElement(o), r, f; y.src = config.url || "https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js"; u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(y); try { t.cookie = u.cookie } catch (p) { } for (t.queue = [], t.version = "1.0", r = ["Event", "Exception", "Metric", "PageView", "Trace", "Dependency"]; r.length;) i("track" + r.pop()); return i("set" + s), i("clear" + s), i(h + a), i(c + a), i(h + v), i(c + v), i("flush"), config.disableExceptionTracking || (r = "onerror", i("_" + r), f = e[r], e[r] = function (config, i, u, e, o) { var s = f && f(config, i, u, e, o); return s !== !0 && t["_" + r](config, i, u, e, o), s }), t }({ instrumentationKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx" }); window.appInsights = appInsights; appInsights.trackPageView();
      window.appInsights = appInsights;      
   </script>
```

The above code will track all events even from Node_Modules of files. but I want to track the custom events and exceptions of only my components file in my angualar 2 application.

Before posting question here I followed the below links but those are angualrJs related not an angualr2 application.
http://www.stevenfollis.com/2015/04/01/using-application-insights-with-angularjs-applications/
https://github.com/johnhidey/angular-appinsights

Can you please tell me how to add the application insights to angular2 application with typescript using visual studio 2015 and also tell me how to access the window.appInsights in my Component files.

-Pradeep

Comment: You could checkout the package ng2-appinsights. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-appinsights

Comment: Thanks harryjohn, for sharing valuable information.

Comment: I created a package for it, with everything updated and working with the latest angular 4.x as well: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/angular-application-insights Available on npm `npm i -S @markpieszak/ng-application-insights`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//-----------Write a Service

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class LoggingService {

        logCustomEvent(fileName: string, methodName: string, eventName: string, msg: string, customData: {}, numericParams: {}): void {
            (<any>window).appInsights.trackEvent(eventName,customData, numericParams);
        };
```

//-----------Usage in components

```
    import { LoggingService } from './logging.service';

    @Component({
        selector: 'component1',
        template: require('./component1.html'),
    })

    export class Component1 {
        constructor(private loggingService: LoggingService) {
        }

        this.loggingService.logCustomEvent('Component1', 'test', 'Testing Angular2 - CustomEvent', 'Test Message', customData, numParams);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." You also must provide your question **as text**, not as images.